# Set Operations can only be used for numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Having picked up an book on introductory real analysis, I find it rather surprising that when sets are defined, the definition is left generally arbitrary. Invariably, definitions of sets are some version of "a collection of objects", with little or no reference to what type of objects they may be. For instance, consider set $A$:

$$A\equiv  ( B,C,D,E ) $$

which contains 4 elements. However, how can one use concepts of neighbourhoods, limit points, bounds etc in such cases? Are such concepts only relevant when we consider sets of numbers?  If this is the case, can we not construct functions which map from $A$ to a subset of numbers, and *then* use concepts that apply only to numbers?

Comment: The concepts you list (neighbourhoods, limit points, bounds, etc.) apply to sets that are equipped with a topology. The members of these sets needn't be numbers. They might be functions, for example. Maybe take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many important concepts in mathematic can be introduced without an explicit use of numbers, but using the properties of objects that are elements of a set.

As an example, consider the points of the space in your room. These, intuitively, are a set, and you have some ''intuitive'' notion of what  means: ''neighbourhoods'', ''bounds'' , ''near'' or ''distant'' etc.

All these intuitions can be mathematically well defined starting from the language of  set theory.  For some concept, (the distance for example) we have to introduce some relation from the elements of the set (the point in the room) and a set of number, but this is not always  essential.